# Text container not adjusting by itself when I change font-family in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, fabricjs

On 'Add text' button Click below function adding text over canvas -

```
jQuery('.addtext').click(function () {

  jQuery('.text_canvas-shape-size-container').css('display','block');

  previewPhotoCanvas(function(){
    var iText = new fabric.IText('Double click to edit text', {
        left: 70,
        top: 140,
        fontFamily: 'Hoefler Text',
        fontSize: 20,
        // fill: '#ff0000',
        //padding: 7,
    });

    canvas.add(iText);
    iText.center();
    iText.setCoords();
    if(for_color!="" && for_color!=undefined){
        iText.fill=for_color;
    }
    canvas.setActiveObject(iText);
    return;
  });  
});
```

It's working fine:

[image: One.png]

While we are changing the `font-family` the container is not adjusting to the new `font-family` size.

Here is code that I am using once the user selects `font-family` from a dropdown:

```
function setFont(font)
{
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (activeObject ) {
        activeObject.fontFamily = font;
        setTimeout(function(){
            canvas.renderAll();
        },1000);
        canvas.renderAll();
        jQuery('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('200');
    } else {
        alert("Please click the text area first");
        jQuery('.dropdown-menu').slideToggle('200');
    }
}
```

Its not behaving right:

[image: two.png]

Comment: thx for editing Paul, do you have any suggestion on this issue ?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution for this?